# C++ object instance stays on list after being destroyed

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Having a bit of a trouble with my supposed-to-be simple c++ code.

I've written a class to describe a Member (as a social media network member), a Member has std::list of followers and std::list of following, both of type Member*, and he can follow/unfollow other members.

Here is the full class:

Member.h

```
class Member {
private:
    bool isCopy;
    static int counter;
    int id;
    list<Member*> following;
    list<Member*> followers;

public:
    Member();
    Member(const Member &p2);
    ~Member();
    void follow(Member &member);
    void unfollow(Member &member);
    int numFollowers();
    int numFollowing();
    static int count();
    bool operator==(const Member &other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Member &other) const;
};
```

Member.cpp

```
int Member::counter = 0;


Member::Member()
{
    counter++;
    id = counter;
    isCopy = false;
    cout << "Constructor ID: " << id << endl;
}

Member::Member(const Member & p2)
{
    this->id = p2.id;
    isCopy = true;
}

Member::~Member()
{
    cout << "Destructor ID: " << this->id << endl;
    if (!isCopy)
    {
        counter--;
    }
}

void Member::follow(Member &member)
{
    if (find(following.begin(), following.end(), &member) == following.end()) 
    {
        following.push_back(&member);
        member.followers.push_back(this);
    }

}

void Member::unfollow(Member &member)
{
    following.remove(&member);
    member.followers.remove(this);
}

int Member::numFollowers()
{
    return followers.size();
}

int Member::numFollowing()
{
    return following.size();
}

int Member::count()
{
    return counter;
}

bool Member::operator==(const Member & other) const
{
    return this->id == other.id;
}

bool Member::operator!=(const Member & other) const
{
    return this->id != other.id;
}
```

Here is a simple code causing me some problems:

```
Member member1, member2;

int main() {
    test();
}

void test(){
    Member member3;
    member2.follow(member3);
    member3.follow(member1);
}
```

After the test function has ended I can see the destructor of member3 being called, but in the main function if I watch the following list of member2 and the followers list of member1 (Both of type Member*) There is still pointer to the member3 address and he has some garbage values in it:

```
{0x00aff720 {isCopy=true (204) id=-858993460 following={ size=3302196 } ...}}
```

My goal here is that when the scope of member3 ends that the size of the following list of member2 and the size of the followers list of member1 will be 0.
Is there any way to address this issue?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Write a destructor in the class `Member` that does this

Comment: There is another (unrelated) problem in your code: If you create two members (IDs are 1 and 2), then destroy the first and create another member, you will have two members with ID 2. I'd assume that is not your intention. This problem always happens unless you only ever destroy the highest ID member. If you only need unique IDs, just keep incrementing the counter. If they also always need to be continuous, that requires more effort.

Comment: Thanks @MaxLanghof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean up the links to `this` in your `followers` and `following` when an object is destroyed.

Something like

```
Member::~Member()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor ID: " << id << std::endl;
    if (!isCopy)
    {
        counter--;
    }
    std::for_each(followers.begin(), followers.end(), [this](Member * other){ other.following.remove(this); });
    std::for_each(following.begin(), following.end(), [this](Member * other){ other.followers.remove(this); });
}
```

Comment: @Tal use a debugger.